# Must a space that is locally injective image of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a manifold?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ s.t. for any $x\in X$ and any open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ that contains $x$, there exists a smaller open set $V\subseteq U$ also containing $x$, so that $V\cap X$ is the image of some injective continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$.

Any $n$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$ clearly satisfies this property; conversely must such an $X$ be an $n$-manifold? Is it true at least for $n=1$? The usual counterexamples such as the topologist's sine curve and the figure 8 are ruled out by this definition.

I am asking in the continuous category, but feel free to consider the smooth variants. Clarification: I mean must $X$ be a topological manifold if we further assume each $f$ is smooth, and must it be a smooth manifold if $f$ is an immersion.

Comment: The only possible way this fails is if the (local) inverse $f^{-1}:f(\omega)\to\omega$ is not continuous/$C^k$ (here $\omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a neighborhood of the origin). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Following on the previous comment, unless I'm misunderstanding the hypothesis, I think the accepted answer to this question provides a negative answer to this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720851/example-of-a-continuous-function-with-a-discontinuous-inverse

Comment: @GregFriedman But this is the figuere 8 which, as the OP says, isn't a counterexample.

Comment: For what it is worth: in 1D the answer is yes. It is not hard to check that if $f:I\to J$ is a continuou bijection between two intervals then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. I suspect this is not true anymore in higher dimensions.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Oops, I missed that in the original post - I also see the problem with it now in terms of the definition. Thanks.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon: Even in 1d, I do not see why the result should be true; you are *using* that the image is homeomorphic to an interval. Or did you mean $m=1$ (and not merily $n=1$)? In that case the answer is trivially positive, because $n=m$: In the case $n=m$ you can just use the domain invariance theorem for continuous injective functions.

Comment: A simple observation: If you restrict $f$ to an arbitrarily large closed ball, then the inverse is continuous (because preimages of closed=compact sets are compact and thus closed). And at least the construction of obvious counterexamples is  then prevented by the fact that images of points from outside large balls have to be covered by other charts as well. Of course, not being able to construct obvious counterexamples does not mean that it can be proved easily.

Comment: @MartinVäth: indeed, you are completely right I am using the fact that the image is already homeomorphic to a segment. The good old "use the conclusion as an hypothesis to prove the conclusion"...

Comment: A possibly interesting non-counterexample is the Alexander horned sphere. It is an continuous embedding of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ that does not have a regular neighbourhood. However $X$ here is still $S^2$.

Comment: In the statement, do you mean that $f$ is a continuous injective map defined on some open neighborhood $W$ (of say 0) such that $f(W) = V \cap X$, or do you really require $f$ to be defined on the whole of $R^n$?

Comment: @TobiasDiez  One needs the whole $\mathbb R^n$ to have a chance to make it work. Your weaker condition is for $n=1$ satisfied by (a version of) the topologist's sine curve:  One just has to pick there $W\subset \mathbb R$ sometimes as an open neighborhood with countably many components.

Comment: @user_1789 thanks this makes sense and I was thinking about similar counterexamples. But if $f$ is required to be defined on the whole of $R^n$, I fail to see how "Any n-manifold embedded in Rm clearly satisfies this property". How do you construct $f$ in this case?

Comment: @TobiasDiez an "embedded n-manifold" is a subspace $X$ of $\mathbb R^m$, such that there is an embedding (i.e. a map $N\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, which is a homeomorphism to its image) of an n-manifold $N$ into $\mathbb R^m$ whose image is $X$. (Thus $X$ with subspace topology is homeomorphic to the n-manifold $N$.) Since the manifold $N$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, so is its image $X$.

Comment: Yes, but "locally homeomorphic" means that $f$ is only defined on an open subset, or not? So you would choose local charts on $N$ and $\mathbb R^m$ such that in these charts the embedding is a map $f: \mathbb R^n \supset U \to \mathbb R^m$ and $f(U)$ is homeomorphic to $X \cap V$ (with $V$ being the chart domain).

Comment: @TobiasDiez By shrinking $U$ (and then $V$), you can assume that $U$ is an open ball. But then you can assume $U=\mathbb R^n$ as well, because an open ball is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here an outline of an argument for an affirmative answer in the case n=1:
By replacing $X$ by $X\cap V$, we can assume $X=g(\mathbb R)$ for a continuous injective map $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$.

We prove (under the given assumptions on X) that $g$ is a proper map to its image (and thus a homeomorphism to its image). Since $g$ is locally on $\mathbb R$ a homeomorphism to its image, it suffices to show that no $x\in X$ is the limit of a sequence $g(t_k)$
with $|t_k|\rightarrow \infty$.

Assume by contradiction, that there is $x\in X$ with $g(t_k)\rightarrow x$ for some $t_k\rightarrow \infty$.

(*) Assume further for simplicity that $g(t)$ converges to $z\neq x$ at the other end of $\mathbb R$, as $t\rightarrow -\infty$.

1. We will show that in this situation $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}g(t)=x$.

Indeed, if there is another accumulation point $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ of $g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$, pick an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $y,z\notin \overline{V}$.

Then $g^{-1}(V)$ consists of a countably infinite disjoint union of nonempty open intervals $I_k\subset \mathbb R$ with compact closures (these intervals tend to $\infty$, since $g$ only accumulates to $x$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$). The images of $J_k:=g(I_k)\subset V$ are homeomorphic to open intervals. The closures of the $J_k$'s in $\mathbb R^m$ are pairwise disjoint and their boundary $\overline{J_k}\setminus J_k\subset \partial V$, consists of two points for each $k$. Thus each $J_k$ is *closed* in $V$.

Assume now $V$ is also such that $X\cap V$ is the image of a continuous injective map $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$. Since we can write $X\cap V= \bigsqcup_k J_k$ as a disjoint union of countably many nonempty closed subsets, the properties of $f$ imply that $\mathbb R$ is the disjoint union of countably many nonempty closed subsets. But this is not possible (e.g. by an application of the Baire category theorem), thus we find a contradiction.

2. Obtain from 1. and (*) a contradiction to our assumptions on $X$:

$g(t)$ converges to $x$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$, but does not accumulate at $x$ for $t\rightarrow -\infty$. Thus $X\setminus {x}$ has  locally near $x$ 3 connected components, which shows that $X\setminus{x}$ locally near x cannot be the continuous image of $\mathbb{R}\setminus p$. This contradicts the assumptions on $X$.

3. Removing the assumption $(*)$.
   There are several cases to consider:

a) If $x$ is not an accumulation point of $g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$
then the argument from 1. goes through by choosing $V$ so small that it contains no such accumulation point, e.g. such that $g((-\infty,0])\cap V=\emptyset$ (and by ignoring $z$). Step 2. applies now as before to yield a contradiction to the assumptions on $X$.

b) If $x$ is an accumulation point of $g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$ but not the limit of $g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$, then the argument from 1. still goes through to derive a contradiction, if we choose $z$ as another accumulation point of $g$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$ (there are now intervals $I_k$ tending to both $\pm \infty$). This contradiction obtained as in 1. shows (without any further assumptions) that no $x\in X$ can be "accumulation point but not limit" at both ends of $\mathbb R$. Up to switching $\pm\infty$, we are thus in the situation c) if $(*)$ does not hold:

c) $x$ is the limit of $g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$ (and an accumulation point, but not the limit, of $g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$).
In this situation, we still follow the basic strategy of 1., picking V and z as before, but the argument changes as slightly: The connected components of $g^{-1}(V)$ can be enumerated as follows. One component has the form $I_0:=(-\infty,a)$, one (potentially different) component is an open interval $I_0'\subset \mathbb R$ containing $g^{-1}(x)$, and the other components form a countable sequence of pairwise disjoint open intervals $I_k, k\geq 1$ tending to $\infty$ (and not containing $x$). The images $g(I_k), k\geq 1$ are closed in V as before, but also $g(I_0\cup I_0')$ is closed in V (since the only accumulation point of $g(I_0)$ in $V\setminus g(I_0)$ is $x\in g(I_0')$) and all of these sets are pairwise disjoint. Thus one obtains a contradiction as in 1., and it follows that $x$ is the limit of $g$ at both $\pm \infty$.
Then $X\setminus x$ has (similar as in 2.) locally near $x$ 4 connected components, and thus it cannot be the continuous image of $\mathbb R\setminus p$.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is true for $n=1$. Here is an outline. Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff and

$\{U\subseteq X\mid U\text{ is open and there exists a continuous bijection }f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U\}$

form a basis of $X$. It suffices to show that each of these $f$ is actually an embedding. It is certainly an embedding restricted to any finite interval, and the only way it can fail to be an embedding is that there exists a sequence $t_n\rightarrow\infty$ s.t. $f(t_n)\rightarrow a$ where $a\in\mathrm{Im}f$ (or a sequence $t_n\rightarrow-\infty$, which is similar).

1. If there is only one such point $a$, then $X$ locally looks like a "cross road" at $a$, and cannot satisfy the definition there, for reason similar to the figure 8.
2. Now suppose there exist two such points $a,b$. Take disjoint neighborhoods $U\ni a,V\ni b$ in $X$, such that there is a continuous bijection $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U$. $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains a sequence $(J_i)_{i\geq 1}$ of open intervals that "go to infinity", and we can assume $\overline{f(J_i)}\cap\overline{f(J_j)}=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$ since $f^{-1}(U)$ is "interleaved" with $f^{-1}(V)$. Then the desired contradiction should follow from  the claim below, which I believe is true.

Claim: if $f$, a continuous bijection to a Hausdorff space, is defined on countably many disjoint open intervals $(J_i)_{i\geq 1}$, and $\overline{f(J_i)}\cap\overline{f(J_j)}=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$, then $\mathrm{Im}f$ cannot be path-connected.